# SQL Oracle: Filtering a query to only show items with either 1 or more than 1 occurance

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the original query:

```
Select * from reportdb.MBC_APPT20156
where (appt_name = 'RV' or appt_name =  'RV EXTENDED' OR appt_name =  'RV        
PSYCHOTHERAPY' OR appt_name = 'RV EVALUATION')
and (dept_abbreviation = 'PSYSLEEP-RUB' OR dept_abbreviation = 'PSYADU-RUB')
and MBC_PROVIDER = '1';
```

I am needing to be able to look at patientsequencenumber that occur both once and that occur more than once in order to compare the two groups.

Comment: can you show input data and expected output

Comment: Make sure you know how to ask your question - read here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  The way you asked, I don't know what table/field you mean by "patientsequencenumber".  HOW WOULD I EVER KNOW THAT???  And sample data would help us, if you want a good answer.

Comment: Well you're more than likely going to be doing a group by on whatever column links the sets, where one is a having count > 1 and the other is = 1.  Your question lacks too many details to be any more specific.